# Android Twitter integration

Tags: android, twitter, xauth

Hello Friends
I have to ingrate X auth to my android apps using Xauth, any body have idea about X auth code for twitter integration , if any body have twitter Xatuh demo apps , plz send me. Twitter provide  cosumer key , secreat key of Xauth for testing pupose.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Zwitscher](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA), who does this. Users are asked for the credentials in [LoginActivity::loginXauth](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/account/LoginActivity.java#L124) and then the [TwitterHelper::generateAccount()](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TwitterHelper.java#L326) checks the validity against Twitter and stores the resulting token.